# Chatbase support in multilanguage

Tags: chatbase

I have two questions:

1) Is chatbase support utf8 text messages? When I am sending herbrew message ,the message under the messages appears with no text (only ellipse).

2) Can I see the history beyond 30 days?

Thanks
Elad

Answer (score 2):

1) Chatbase does support utf8 text, so the messages should appear in the messages table. If you email our alias, chatbase-feedback@google.com, with your API key, I can take a look at what could be happening.

2) Right now our reports are fixed at a maximum of 30 days, however we are planning on adding the ability to view date using your own time ranges within the next few months.

Comment: Thanks I sent you an email.